# Invalid XML element name while it's exactly one that is expected

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

I am trying to validate an XML document against an XSD, and I can't seem to solve the following error:

```
Element name 'Elektriciteit' is invalid.

One of the following is expected:
 - VloeibareBiobrandstof
 - GasvormigeBiobrandstof
 - Elektriciteit
 - GasvormigeHernieuwbareBrandstof

Error indicated by:
 {https://www.emissieautoriteit.nl/rev}
with code:xml(cvc-complex-type.2.4.a)
```

The XSD is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema
    version="4.4.0"
    targetNamespace="https://www.emissieautoriteit.nl/rev"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns="https://www.emissieautoriteit.nl/rev"
    >

<xs:element name="Inboekingen" type="Inboekingen">
    <xs:unique name="AdministratienummerConstraint">        
        <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
        <xs:field xpath="Administratienummer"/>
    </xs:unique>
    <xs:unique name="NummerBewijsVanDuurzaamheidConstraint">
        <xs:selector xpath="*"/>
        <xs:field xpath="NummerBewijsVanDuurzaamheid"/>
    </xs:unique>
</xs:element>

<xs:complexType name="Inboekingen">
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="VloeibareBiobrandstof" type="VloeibareBiobrandstof"/>
        <xs:element name="GasvormigeBiobrandstof" type="GasvormigeBiobrandstof"/>
        <xs:element name="Elektriciteit" type="Elektriciteit"/>
        <xs:element name="GasvormigeHernieuwbareBrandstof" type="GasvormigeHernieuwbareBrandstof"/>
    </xs:choice>
    <xs:attribute name="Versie" use="required" type="Versie"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="VloeibareBiobrandstof">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Administratienummer" type="Tekstveld100"/>
        <xs:element name="BegindatumLevering" minOccurs="0" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="EinddatumLevering" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="SoortBiobrandstof" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="Bestemming" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="TypeLevering" type="TypeLevering"/>
        <xs:element name="Locatie" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="Duurzaamheidssysteem" minOccurs="0" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="NummerBewijsVanDuurzaamheid" minOccurs="0" type="Tekstveld100"/>
        <xs:element name="SerienummerGvO" minOccurs="0" type="SerienummerGvO"/>
        <xs:element name="Hoeveelheid" type="Hoeveelheid"/>
        <xs:element name="OndersteVerbrandingswaarde" nillable="true" type="Verbrandingswaarde"/>
        <xs:element name="Biocomponent" nillable="true" type="Biocomponent" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:choice>
            <xs:element name="GrondstofEenheidPercentage" type="GrondstofEenheidPercentage"/>
            <xs:element name="GrondstofEenheidGJ" type="GrondstofEenheidGJ"/>
        </xs:choice>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GasvormigeBiobrandstof">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Administratienummer" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="BegindatumLevering" type="Datum"/> <!-- De BegindatumLevering mag gelijk zijn aan de EinddatumLevering. -->
        <xs:element name="EinddatumLevering" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="Bestemming" type="Tekstveld50"/> <!-- Raadpleeg de referentiegegevens in het Register Energie voor Vervoer voor een overzicht van de toegestane waarden. -->
        <xs:element name="TypeGasLevering" type="TypeGasLevering"/> <!-- Gastransportnet of DirecteLijn -->
        <xs:element name="SerienummerGvO" type="SerienummerGvO"/> <!-- Er dient in het systeem een GvO opgevoerd te zijn met dit serienummer -->
        <xs:element name="GrondstofPercentage" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="GrondstofPercentage"/>
        <xs:element name="Aansluiting" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Aansluiting"/> <!-- De opgenomen waarde voor het veld Aansluiting dient door de rekeningbevoegde te zijn opgevoerd  bij de rekening. De waarde dient exact overeen te komen met een naam van een bij de rekening opgevoerde aansluiting. --> 
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Elektriciteit">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Administratienummer" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="BegindatumLevering" type="Datum"/> <!-- De BegindatumLevering mag gelijk zijn aan de EinddatumLevering. -->
        <xs:element name="EinddatumLevering" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="Bestemming" type="Tekstveld50"/> <!-- Raadpleeg de referentiegegevens in het Register Energie voor Vervoer voor een overzicht van de toegestane waarden. -->
        <xs:element name="TypeElektriciteitsLevering" type="TypeElektriciteitsLevering"/> <!-- OpwekEigenLocatie, Elektriciteitsnet of DirecteLijn -->
        <xs:element name="SerienummerGvO" minOccurs="0" type="SerienummerGvoElektriciteit"/> <!-- Enkel van toepassing in geval TypeElektriciteitsLevering "DirecteLijn" is. Er dient in het systeem een GvO opgevoerd te zijn met dit serienummer -->
        <xs:element name="Aansluiting" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="Aansluiting"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GasvormigeHernieuwbareBrandstof">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Administratienummer" type="Tekstveld100"/> <!-- Anders dan bij een handmatige inboeking is het administratienummer bij import verplicht. Reden hiervoor is dat indien de import van inboekingen op inhoudelijke validaties mislukt, dit nummer gebruikt kan worden om de inboeking te vinden waar de fout optreedt. -->   
        <xs:element name="BegindatumLevering" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="EinddatumLevering" type="Datum"/>
        <xs:element name="SoortGasvormigeHernieuwbareBrandstof" type="Tekstveld50"/> <!-- Raadpleeg de referentiegegevens in het Register Energie voor Vervoer voor een overzicht van de toegestane waarden. -->
        <xs:element name="Bestemming" type="Tekstveld50"/> <!-- Raadpleeg de referentiegegevens in het Register Energie voor Vervoer voor een overzicht van de toegestane waarden. -->  
        <xs:element name="Locatie" type="Tekstveld50"/> <!-- De opgenomen waarde voor het veld Locatie dient door de rekeningbevoegde zijn opgevoerd  bij de rekening. De waarde dient exact overeen te komen met een naam van een bij de rekening opgevoerde locatie. --> 
        <xs:element name="Hoeveelheid" type="Hoeveelheid"/> <!-- Dit is de grondslag voor de berekening van het aantal HBE's. De verwachte eenheid is afhankelijk van de gekozen brandstof. -->
        <xs:element name="SerienummerGvO" type="SerienummerGvOWaterstof"/> <!-- Indien de brandstof een GvO vereist, moet een GvO opgevoerd worden waarvan het serienummer in het systeem is opgevoerd of geimporteerd-->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Definitie van de overige complexTypes -->
<xs:complexType name="GrondstofEenheidPercentage">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GrondstofPercentage" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="GrondstofPercentage"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GrondstofEenheidGJ">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="GrondstofGJ" maxOccurs="unbounded" type="GrondstofGJ"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GrondstofPercentage">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Grondstofnaam" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="BijdrageAanLevering" type="BijdrageAanLevering"/><!-- Voor de inboeking dient de gesommeerde BijdrageAanLevering over alle grondstoffen 100 procent te zijn. -->
        <xs:element name="IngebruiknameProductieInstallatie" type="IngebruiknameProductieInstallatie"/><!-- Met dit attribuut geeft u aan of de productie installatie welke is gebruikt voor de verwerking van de grondstof in gebruik is genomen op "05-10-2015 of eerder" (voor6oktober2015), op "06-10-2015 t/m 31-12-2020" (vanaf6oktober2015), of "01-01-2021 of later" (vanaf1januari2021) -->
        <xs:element name="Broeikasgasemissie" type="Broeikasgasemissie"/> <!-- Aan de hand van de opgegeven Broeikasgasemissie en de voor het moment van inboeking (periode) geldende referentiewaarde wordt het broeikasgasemissiereductiepercentage berekend. Deze dient groter te zijn of gelijk aan het geldende minimale reductiepercentage. -->
        <xs:element name="LandVanHerkomst" type="LandVanHerkomst"/>
        <xs:element name="NummerVanDubbeltellingsverklaring" type="NummerVanDubbeltellingsverklaring"/> <!-- Door dit attribuut te vullen geeft u aan dat u de de grondstof dubbeltellend wilt claimen. De opgenomen waarde voor het veld NummerVanDubbeltellingsVerklaring dient door de rekeningbevoegde zijn opgevoerd bij de rekening. De waarde dient exact overeen te komen met een nummer van een bij de rekening opgevoerde dubbeltellingsverklaring. De betreffende dubbeltellingsverklaring dient, rekening houdend met de reeds in het Register opgevoerde inboekingen, voldoende energieinhoud te vertegenwoordigen voor de inboekingen die geimporteerd worden. -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="GrondstofGJ">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Grondstofnaam" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="BijdrageAanLeveringGJ" type="BijdrageAanLeveringGJ"/> <!-- Voor de inboeking dient de gesommeerde BijdrageAanLevering over alle grondstoffen gelijk te zijn aan de energieinhoud van het hernieuwbare deel van de inboeking. -->
        <xs:element name="IngebruiknameProductieInstallatie" type="IngebruiknameProductieInstallatie"/><!-- Met dit attribuut geeft u aan of de productie installatie welke is gebruikt voor de verwerking van de grondstof in gebruik is genomen op "05-10-2015 of eerder" (voor6oktober2015), op "06-10-2015 t/m 31-12-2020" (vanaf6oktober2015), of "01-01-2021 of later" (vanaf1januari2021) -->
        <xs:element name="Broeikasgasemissie" type="Broeikasgasemissie"/><!-- Aan de hand van de opgegeven Broeikasgasemissie en de voor het moment van inboeking (periode) geldende referentiewaarde wordt het broeikasgasemissiereductiepercentage berekend. Deze dient groter te zijn of gelijk aan het geldende minimale reductiepercentage. -->
        <xs:element name="LandVanHerkomst" type="LandVanHerkomst"/>
        <xs:element name="NummerVanDubbeltellingsverklaring" type="NummerVanDubbeltellingsverklaring"/><!-- Door dit attribuut te vullen geeft u aan dat u de de grondstof dubbeltellend wilt claimen. De opgenomen waarde voor het veld NummerVanDubbeltellingsVerklaring dient door de rekeningbevoegde zijn opgevoerd bij de rekening. De waarde dient exact overeen te komen met een nummer van een bij de rekening opgevoerde dubbeltellingsverklaring. De betreffende dubbeltellingsverklaring dient, rekening houdend met de reeds in het Register opgevoerde inboekingen, voldoende energieinhoud te vertegenwoordigen voor de inboekingen die geimporteerd worden. -->
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="Aansluiting">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Aansluitingnaam" type="Tekstveld50"/>
        <xs:element name="Hoeveelheid" type="Hoeveelheid"/> <!-- Dit is bij Elektriciteit de grondslag voor de berekening van het aantal HBE's. De verwachte eenheid is kWh. Bij GasvormigeBiobrandstof geeft u de hoeveelheid op in kg. -->
        <xs:element name="Toelichting" type="MemoVeld"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<!-- Definitie van overige simpleTypes -->
<xs:simpleType name="Verbrandingswaarde">
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Versie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9].[0-9].[0-9]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Tekstveld50">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="50"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Tekstveld100">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="100"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="MemoVeld">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:maxLength value="200"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Datum"> <!-- Het formaat is: jjjj-mm-ddZ. -->
    <xs:restriction base="xs:date">
        <xs:pattern value="[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}[Z]"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Hoeveelheid">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:long">
        <xs:minExclusive value="0"/>
        <xs:totalDigits value="13"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="SerienummerGvO">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value = "[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{6}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="SerienummerGvOWaterstof">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value = "H2.[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\.[0-9]{3}\.[0-9]{6}"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="SerienummerGvoElektriciteit">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value = "8716867999938[0-9]{17}"/> <!-- 8716867999938 is het EAN van CertiQ -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Broeikasgasemissie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:minExclusive value = "-100"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value = "100"/>
        <xs:pattern value = "-?\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="BijdrageAanLevering">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:minExclusive value = "0"/>
        <xs:maxInclusive value = "100"/>
        <xs:pattern value = "\d{0,3}(\.\d{1,2})?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="BijdrageAanLeveringGJ">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:double">
        <xs:minExclusive value = "0"/>
        <xs:pattern value = "\d{0,15}(\.\d{1,3})?"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="NummerVanDubbeltellingsverklaring">
    <xs:restriction base="Tekstveld50">
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!-- Definitie van simpleTypes met enumeration -->
<xs:simpleType name="IngebruiknameProductieInstallatie">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="voor6oktober2015"/> <!-- 05-10-2015 of eerder -->
        <xs:enumeration value="vanaf6oktober2015"/> <!--  06-10-2015 tot en met 31-12-2020 -->
        <xs:enumeration value="vanaf1januari2021"/> <!--  01-01-2021 of later -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="TypeGasLevering">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="Gastransportnet"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="DirecteLijn"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Biocomponent">
    <xs:restriction base ="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value=""/>
        <xs:enumeration value="KleinerOfGelijkAan50Procent"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="GroterDan50Procent"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<!--
<xs:simpleType name="TypeGasLeveringGasvormigHernieuwbaar">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="???"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="???"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
-->

<xs:simpleType name="TypeLevering">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="AanEenAGP"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="UitslagTotVerbruikAanVervoer"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="TypeElektriciteitsLevering">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="OpwekEigenLocatie"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Elektriciteitsnet"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="DirecteLijn"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="LandVanHerkomst">
    <xs:annotation>
        <xs:documentation>
            Dit zijn de 2 letter landcodes volgens ISO3166.
        </xs:documentation>
    </xs:annotation>
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="AF"/> <!-- AFGHANISTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AX"/> <!--  ALAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AL"/> <!-- ALBANIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DZ"/> <!-- ALGERIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AS"/> <!-- AMERICAN SAMOA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AD"/> <!-- ANDORRA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AO"/> <!-- ANGOLA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AI"/> <!-- ANGUILLA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AQ"/> <!-- ANTARCTICA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AG"/> <!-- ANTIGUA AND BARBUDA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AR"/> <!-- ARGENTINA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AM"/> <!-- ARMENIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AW"/> <!-- ARUBA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AU"/> <!-- AUSTRALIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AT"/> <!-- AUSTRIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AZ"/> <!-- AZERBAIJAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BS"/> <!-- BAHAMAS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BH"/> <!-- BAHREIN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BD"/> <!-- BANGLADESH -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BB"/> <!-- BARBADOS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BY"/> <!-- BELARUS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BE"/> <!-- BELGIUM -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BZ"/> <!-- BELIZE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BJ"/> <!-- BENIN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BM"/> <!-- BERMUDA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BT"/> <!-- BHUTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BO"/> <!-- BOLIVIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BQ"/> <!-- BONAIRE SINT EUSTATIUS AND SABA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BA"/> <!-- BOSNIA AND HERZEGOVINA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BW"/> <!-- BOTSWANA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BV"/> <!-- BOUVET ISLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BR"/> <!-- BRAZIL -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IO"/> <!-- BRITISH INDIAN OCEAN TERRITORY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BN"/> <!-- BRUNEI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BG"/> <!-- BULGARIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BF"/> <!-- BURKINA FASO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BI"/> <!-- BURUNDI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KH"/> <!-- CAMBODIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CM"/> <!-- CAMEROON -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CA"/> <!-- CANADA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CV"/> <!-- CAPE VERDE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KY"/> <!-- CAYMAN ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CF"/> <!-- CENTRAL AFRICAN REPUBLIC -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TD"/> <!-- CHAD -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CL"/> <!-- CHILE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CN"/> <!-- CHINA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CX"/> <!-- CHRISTMAS ISLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CC"/> <!-- COCOS ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CO"/> <!-- COLOMBIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KM"/> <!-- COMOROS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CG"/> <!-- REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CD"/> <!-- DEMOCRATIC REPUBLIC OF THE CONGO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CK"/> <!-- COOK ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CR"/> <!-- COSTA RICA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CI"/> <!-- IVORY COAST -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HR"/> <!-- CROATIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CU"/> <!-- CUBA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CW"/> <!-- CURACAO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CY"/> <!-- CYPRUS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CZ"/> <!-- CZECH REPUBLIC -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DK"/> <!-- DENMARK -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DJ"/> <!-- DJIBOUTI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DM"/> <!-- DOMINICA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DO"/> <!-- DOMINICAN REPUBLIC -->
        <xs:enumeration value="EC"/> <!-- ECUADOR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="EG"/> <!-- EGYPT -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SV"/> <!-- EL SALVADOR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GQ"/> <!-- EQUATORIAL GUINEA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ER"/> <!-- ERITREA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="EE"/> <!-- ESTONIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ET"/> <!-- ETHIOPIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FK"/> <!-- FALKLAND ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FO"/> <!-- FAROE ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FJ"/> <!-- FIJI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FI"/> <!-- FINLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FR"/> <!-- FRANCE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GF"/> <!-- FRENCH GUIANA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PF"/> <!-- FRENCH POLYNESIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TF"/> <!-- FRENCH SOUTHERN TERRITORIES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GA"/> <!-- GABON -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GM"/> <!-- GAMBIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GE"/> <!-- GEORGIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="DE"/> <!-- GERMANY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GH"/> <!-- GHANA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GI"/> <!-- GIBRALTAR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GR"/> <!-- GREECE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GL"/> <!-- GREENLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GD"/> <!-- GRENADA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GP"/> <!-- GUADELOUPE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GU"/> <!-- GUAM -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GT"/> <!-- GUATEMALA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GG"/> <!-- GREENLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GN"/> <!-- GUINEA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GW"/> <!-- GUINEA BISSAU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GY"/> <!-- GUYANA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HT"/> <!-- HAITI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HM"/> <!-- GREENLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VA"/> <!-- HOLY SEE VATICAN CITY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HN"/> <!-- HONDURAS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HK"/> <!-- HONG KONG -->
        <xs:enumeration value="HU"/> <!-- HUNGARY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IS"/> <!-- ICELAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IN"/> <!-- INDIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ID"/> <!-- INDONESIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IR"/> <!-- IRAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IQ"/> <!-- IRAQ -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IE"/> <!-- IRELAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IM"/> <!-- ISLE OF MAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IL"/> <!-- ISRAEL -->
        <xs:enumeration value="IT"/> <!-- ITALY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="JM"/> <!-- JAMAICA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="JP"/> <!-- JAPAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="JE"/> <!-- JERSEY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="JO"/> <!-- JORDAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KZ"/> <!-- KAZAKHSTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KE"/> <!-- KENYA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KI"/> <!-- KIRIBATI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KP"/> <!-- NORTH KOREA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KR"/> <!-- SOUTH KOREA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KW"/> <!-- KUWAIT -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KG"/> <!-- KYRGYZSTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LA"/> <!-- LAOS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LV"/> <!-- LATVIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LB"/> <!-- LEBANON -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LS"/> <!-- LESOTHO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LR"/> <!-- LIBERIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LY"/> <!-- LIBYA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LI"/> <!-- LIECHTENSTEIN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LT"/> <!-- LITHUANIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LU"/> <!-- LUXEMBOURG -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MO"/> <!-- MACAU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MK"/> <!-- MACEDONIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MG"/> <!-- MADAGASCAR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MW"/> <!-- MALAWI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MY"/> <!-- MALAYSIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MV"/> <!-- MALDIVES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ML"/> <!-- MALI -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MT"/> <!-- MALTA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MH"/> <!-- MARSHALL ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MQ"/> <!-- MARTINIQUE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MR"/> <!-- MAURITANIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MU"/> <!-- MAURITIUS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="YT"/> <!-- MAYOTTE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MX"/> <!-- MEXICO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="FM"/> <!-- MICRONESIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MD"/> <!-- MOLDOVA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MC"/> <!-- MONACO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MN"/> <!-- MONGOLIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ME"/> <!-- MONTENEGRO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MS"/> <!-- MONTSERRAT -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MA"/> <!-- MOROCCO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MZ"/> <!-- MOZAMBIQUE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MM"/> <!-- MYANMAR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NA"/> <!-- NAMIBIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NR"/> <!-- NAURU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NP"/> <!-- NEPAL -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NL"/> <!-- NETHERLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NC"/> <!-- NEW CALEDONIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NZ"/> <!-- NEW ZEALAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NI"/> <!-- NICARAGUA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NE"/> <!-- NIGER -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NG"/> <!-- NIGERIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NU"/> <!-- NIUE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NF"/> <!-- NORFOLK ISLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MP"/> <!-- NORTHERN MARIANA ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="NO"/> <!-- NORWAY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="OM"/> <!-- OMAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PK"/> <!-- PAKISTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PW"/> <!-- PALAU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PS"/> <!-- PALESTINIAN TERRITORY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PA"/> <!-- PANAMA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PG"/> <!-- PAPUA NEW GUINEA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PY"/> <!-- PARAGUAY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PE"/> <!-- PERU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PH"/> <!-- PHILIPPINES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PN"/> <!-- PITCAIRN ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PL"/> <!-- POLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PT"/> <!-- PORTUGAL -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PR"/> <!-- PUERTO RICO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="QA"/> <!-- QATAR -->
        <xs:enumeration value="RE"/> <!-- REUNION -->
        <xs:enumeration value="RO"/> <!-- ROMANIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="RU"/> <!-- RUSSIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="RW"/> <!-- RWANDA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="BL"/> <!-- SAINT BARTHELEMY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SH"/> <!-- SAINT HELENA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="KN"/> <!-- SAINT KITTS AND NEVIS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LC"/> <!-- SAINT LUCIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="MF"/> <!-- RWANDA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="PM"/> <!-- SAINT PIERRE AND MIQUELON -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VC"/> <!-- SAINT VINCENT AND THE GRENADINES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="WS"/> <!-- SAMOA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SM"/> <!-- SAN MARINO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ST"/> <!-- SAO TOME AND PRINCIPE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SA"/> <!-- SAUDI ARABIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SN"/> <!-- SENEGAL -->
        <xs:enumeration value="RS"/> <!-- SERBIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SC"/> <!-- SEYCHELLES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SL"/> <!-- SIERRA LEONE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SG"/> <!-- SINGAPORE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SX"/> <!-- SINT MAARTEN DUTCH PART -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SK"/> <!-- SLOVAKIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SI"/> <!-- SLOVENIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SB"/> <!-- SOLOMON ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SO"/> <!-- SOMALIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ZA"/> <!-- SOUTH AFRICA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GS"/> <!-- SOUTH GEORGIA AND THE SOUTH SANDWICH ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SS"/> <!-- SOUTH SUDAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ES"/> <!-- SPAIN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="LK"/> <!-- SRI LANKA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SD"/> <!-- SUDAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SR"/> <!-- SURINAME -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SJ"/> <!-- SVALBARD -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SZ"/> <!-- SWAZILAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SE"/> <!-- SWEDEN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="CH"/> <!-- SWITZERLAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="SY"/> <!-- SYRIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TW"/> <!-- TAIWAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TJ"/> <!-- TAJIKISTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TZ"/> <!-- TANZANIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TH"/> <!-- THAILAND -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TL"/> <!-- TIMOR LESTE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TG"/> <!-- TOGO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TK"/> <!-- TOKELAU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TO"/> <!-- TONGA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TT"/> <!-- TRINIDAD AND TOBAGO -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TN"/> <!-- TUNISIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TR"/> <!-- TURKEY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TM"/> <!-- TURKMENISTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TC"/> <!-- TURKS AND CAICOS ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="TV"/> <!-- TUVALU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="UG"/> <!-- UGANDA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="UA"/> <!-- UKRAINE -->
        <xs:enumeration value="AE"/> <!-- UNITED ARAB EMIRATES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="GB"/> <!-- UNITED KINGDOM -->
        <xs:enumeration value="US"/> <!-- UNITED STATES -->
        <xs:enumeration value="UM"/> <!-- UNITED STATES MINOR OUTLYING ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="UY"/> <!-- URUGUAY -->
        <xs:enumeration value="UZ"/> <!-- UZBEKISTAN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VU"/> <!-- VANUATU -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VE"/> <!-- VENEZUELA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VN"/> <!-- VIETNAM -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VG"/> <!-- BRITISH VIRGIN ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="VI"/> <!-- US VIRGIN ISLANDS -->
        <xs:enumeration value="WF"/> <!-- WALLIS AND FUTUNA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="EH"/> <!-- WESTERN SAHARA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="YE"/> <!-- YEMEN -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ZM"/> <!-- ZAMBIA -->
        <xs:enumeration value="ZW"/> <!-- ZIMBABWE -->
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

</xs:schema>
```

The XML document is as follows:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Inboekingen xmlns="https://www.emissieautoriteit.nl/rev" Versie="4.4.0">
    <Elektriciteit>
        <BegindatumLevering>2023-01-01</BegindatumLevering>
        <EinddatumLevering>2023-12-31</EinddatumLevering>
        <Bestemming>Wegvervoer</Bestemming>
        <TypeElektriciteitsLevering>Elektriciteitsnet</TypeElektriciteitsLevering>
        <Aansluiting>
            <Aansluitingnaam>2023010101 Locatie 1</Aansluitingnaam>
            <Hoeveelheid>12345</Hoeveelheid>
        </Aansluiting>
    </Elektriciteit>
</Inboekingen>
```

What am I doing wrong?

I tried importing and switching namespaces etc, but the error doesn't get resolved. While the `Inboekingen` element doesn't produce any error, I find it strange that it's child element does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you expect all elements in the instance to be in the target namespace of the schema you need to declare `elementFormDefault="qualified"` on the `xs:schema`.

Or, for your schema to make (partly) sense, you could only put the root element of the instance into the target namespace but then make sure the children and descendant elements are in no namespace.

Comment: Thanks, this does indeed solve the issue!